# Вывод из БД с помощью PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Пытаюсь выводить с помощью PDO SQL, но в итоге ничего не выводит, и понять ничего не могу.

```
class OutTask extends DataBase{

public function outTask(){
    $out_task_sql = "SELECT * FROM `test`";
    $run_sql = $this->pdo->query($out_task_sql);
    $run_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    return $run_sql;
} }


$out_task = new OutTask;
$out_task->outTask();
```

Comment: а где тут "вывод"?

Comment: Через SELECT создается новый член класса OutTask и с помощью функции, оно должно выводить массив

Comment: нет, оно не должно ничего выводить. для вывода в php есть специальные функции

Comment: Ну и до кучи - результат `fetchAll` __никуда не присваивается__.

Comment: Короче, ничего из данного материала не помогло, так-как ошибка была не в запросе, а в выводе. $out_task не может принять значение, которое возвращается с функции, спасибо за ничего не давший мне совет.

Comment: Ты просто не умеешь читать внимательно материал.